# MarkLogic: Connectors to SPSS

Tags: marklogic, spss-modeler

I have a question regarding connecting MarkLogic and SPSS Modeler
 - I have my data stored in MarkLogic.
 - I want to do text mining in SPSS using the data stored in MarkLogic.
 - How do I connect SPSS and MarkLogic?

Answer (score 1):

Probably with ODBC: http://developer.marklogic.com/products/odbc

It will be up to you to decide how best to map your XML documents to SQL.

Comment: To my understanding SPSS indeed supports SQL databases. The link provided by Mike provides Windows ODBC drivers, and links to documentation to setup MarkLogic for use with ODBC/SQL..